# L.circle wrong radius in Mapbox

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I made two L.circles. One with radius 1233685 and the other with radius 1505615. But for some reason the 1st circle is bigger than the second.Why is that happening?
I took the log of both the circle objects.It is as follows:
1st circle:

_container: g
_initHooksCalled: true
_latlng: o.LatLng
_leaflet_events: Object
_leaflet_id: 12437
_mRadius: 1233685
_map: o.Class.extend.e
_path: path
_point: o.Point
_popup: o.Class.extend.e
_popupHandlersAdded: true
_radius: 63
options: Object
**proto**: o.Class.extend.i

2nd circle:

_container: g
_initHooksCalled: true
_latlng: o.LatLng
_leaflet_events: Object
_leaflet_id: 12438
_mRadius: 1505615
_map: o.Class.extend.e
_path: path
_point: o.Point
_popup: o.Class.extend.e
_popupHandlersAdded: true
_radius: 91
options: Object
**proto**: o.Class.extend.i

As you can see mRadius in both case is fine but theres another property radius whose value is larger for circle with smaller mRadius.Is it because  of that I am getting wrong circle radius. 
I am using mapbox 2.2.1

Comment: Are your 2 circles at different latitudes? Radius is specified in meters, which are adjusted by the projection depending on latitude (the higher, the more pixels per meter for default CRS).

Comment: yeah..they are at different latitudes.What can I do so that pixels per metre be same for all latitudes?

Comment: Or can we provide radius in pixels? I know there is a L.circleMarker but if we use that the radius doesn't change on zooming in or out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your circles have to represent a distance on Earth, the size adjustment is the behaviour you should look for.

Now if you really want the size to be independent from latitude (whatever your reasons), please refer to these posts:

- [leaflet fixed size circle on map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33233646/leaflet-fixed-size-circle-on-map/33369434#33369434)
- [Leaflet circle radius doesn't matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31586577/leaflet-circle-radius-doesnt-matter)
- [Leaflet Circle radius changing dependant on y/lng coords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25034291/leaflet-circle-radius-changing-dependant-on-y-lng-coords)

Comment: thanks ghybs, it helped a lot .As I was using circles to compare values of some properties, thats why I needed it to be independent of lat/long.